# How to maintain responsiveness of the UI element in React Native for android Devices?

Tags: android, react-native

I have made a UI Screen in my full hd device and it is rendering quite well.But rendering in HD device makes the whole design messy.

The whole styling property is going haywire even in the devices which is having the same resolution but different screen Sizes.

How Can we make responsive design for the app.

Comment: Go through this: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html Perhaps you missed `smallest-width` qualifier.

Comment: Hey I am Using React Native for developing the UI any Help would be helpful